# Getting syntax error in @PROMPT Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, business-objects

SAP Bo has generated a SQL query for a report which is not working in Oracle SQL Developer. I am getting 'missing expression' error.
Below is the code, please help me finding out the error here.
and also help me to understand the role of @PROMPT here.

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN MATERIAL IN @PROMPT('Enter materials which may not be shipped to SIMS:','C',,Multi,Free,Persistent)  OR material IN @PROMPT'Enter materials which may not be shipped to SIMS(2):','C',,Multi,Free,Persistent) 
    THEN 'Not SIMS'
    WHEN
material IN @PROMPT('Enter materials which can be shipped to SIMS:','C',,Multi,Free,Persistent) 
    THEN 'SIMS'
END
FROM
Materials;
```

Expecting query should work as the same is working in SAP BO.

Comment: [@PROMPT](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_BUSINESSOBJECTS_BUSINESS_INTELLIGENCE_PLATFORM/3d4f417fd0764f909c0ef7931e19fe1a/466795506e041014910aba7db0e91070.html) is SAP syntax, not SQL. You might be looking for bind variables or substitution variables?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN MATERIAL IN(&Enter_NON_ShippableMaterials_SIMS) OR MATERIAL IN(&Enter_NON_ShippableMaterials_SIMS_2) THEN 'Not SIMS'
    WHEN MATERIAL IN(&Enter_SIMS_ShippableMaterials) THEN 'SIMS'
  END "SIMS_OR_NOT"
FROM
```

You will be prompted to input data 3 times. If data are of type VarChar2 and you need to enter a list of data as input then do it within single quotes separated by comma - 'MAT_1', 'MAT_2', ....
Regards...